# MySQL Query CSV to output not a file

Tags: mysql, csv, select

I want to make a select to mySQL and return the resulting recordset as CSV but not saving it into a file.

I have this:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
WHERE foo = 'bar'
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I have tried to change it into:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
WHERE foo = 'bar'
INTO @out
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But it doesn't work.

The use case is to give users the option to download CSV files from data driven web site. To do so I need to output the CSV file/data to the browser.

How to do?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.

Comment: To give some hints you would need to be creative with `CONCAT()` and you would most likely also need to use nested `REPLACE()` functions to escape the [Special Character Escape Sequences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)

Comment: @Raymond, yes, I know I can do it manually, but if mySQL has a function for outputting it correctly to a file, then why not same to a variable?

Comment: *" but if mySQL has a function for outputting it correctly to a file, then why not same to a variable?"* no idea iám not a Oracle dev do you really want me to answer that question?

Comment: @Raymond, ok, so the triviality here is the fact that mySQL does not provide this functionality. Why not say so if that's the case? But yes, it is possible to do with CONCAT_WS, QUOTE and REPLACE, but much more to write... :-)

Comment: *"Why not say so if that's the case?"* i wasnt clear enough i geuss with the comment *"you would **need** to be creative with CONCAT() and you would most likely also need to use nested REPLACE()"* i meant implicit with that comment there wasn't a better function or method.

Comment: *"The use case is to give users the option to download CSV files from data driven web site. To do so I need to output the CSV file/data to the browser."* now i also read your edit this should be handled by application code and not MySQL itself

Comment: @Raymond, yes, the last part must be done by application code, but the CSV output could be done in either SQL or application code. A mySQL procedure could be considered.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly and you need to import data first in a table.Mysql command  for this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html